# How to open and input keystrokes on a seperate .exe file on c++? (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, exe, keystrokes

I'm a noob when it comes coding and even more so when coding in c++.

For short backstory, a family member is getting annoyed at how long it takes to input all of their information onto a program they use regularly. The information that is input never changes, so I was hoping to automate the process. For example, sending the keystrokes "username" [TAB] "password" [ENTER]

I was hoping it was a simple bit of windows.h code but I haven't been so lucky looking through threads. Any ideas?

Comment: Entering username and password is supposed to be a boring process, unless you're trying to brute force crack it.

Comment: FYI, there are plenty of password keeper programs out there already that serve just this purpose.

Comment: Although I'm sure it could be used for trying to brute force a password, I really just need to know to automate a process in another program.

Comment: Use ``SendInput`` API or ``keybd_event`` (deprecated)

Comment: and I guess it's important to add that I will be needing to add a lot more inputs than just a username and password.

Comment: Look up password manager programs, which are designed to securely store all your passwords locked away with a master password, and autofill them when you need. If you want to do this yourself, I think the easiest way is to just learn how to write a script in [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/). It's much easier than trying to write a windows program in C++.

Comment: I never used it by myself - just read about it, but it might be a solution: [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/): _AutoHotkey is a free, open-source scripting language for Windows that allows users to easily create small to complex scripts for all kinds of tasks such as: form fillers, auto-clicking, macros, etc._ (I'm not related to this software. Sorry, if it looks like advertising.) ;-)

Comment: I would suggest [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) Easier to write than C++ for this purpose